# Using Fedex REST Rates API, why do I only get GROUND rates?

Tags: php, rest, fedex

I am passing in

```
Array
(
    [accountNumber] => Array
        (
            [value] => ***
        )

    [requestedShipment] => Array
        (
            [shipper] => Array
                (
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [city] => Safety Harbor
                            [stateOrProvinceCode] => FL
                            [postalCode] => 34695
                            [countryCode] => US
                            [residential] => 1
                        )

                )

            [recipient] => Array
                (
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [city] => Boston
                            [stateOrProvinceCode] => MA
                            [postalCode] => 02134
                            [countryCode] => US
                        )

                )

            [rateRequestType] => Array
                (
                    [0] => LIST
                )

            [shipDateStamp] => 2023-06-14
            [pickupType] => DROPOFF_AT_FEDEX_LOCATION
            [requestedPackageLineItems] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [declaredValue] => Array
                                (
                                    [amount] => 123
                                    [currency] => USD
                                )

                            [weight] => Array
                                (
                                    [units] => LB
                                    [value] => 12
                                )

                        )

                )

            [documentShipment] => 
            [packagingType] => YOUR_PACKAGING
            [groupShipment] => 1
        )

    [carrierCodes] => Array
        (
            [0] => FDXG
            [1] => FDXE
        )

)
```

but all I get back in the `rateReplyDetails` is an entry for Ground. I would have thought that because I didn't set `serviceType` that I'd get a list of rates for all possible services.

Comment: Fedex has [phone support](https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/support.html) for their developer portal, I can't image that you'll get better results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test endpoint doesn't give you a full set of rates!  When you're ready to go beyond basic testing, you need to use the live site (with a new key and secret).  The guys at Fedex support are very helpful (especially considering the task is "hey, can you help me debug my code?") - you just have to explain what you're doing and they will watch the server to see what's happening.